# Rounded Border for UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios6, container-view

I want to have a border around my UITableView, and have the corners rounded. I know this is possible on Table Cells, but wondering what the best way to do this is. I'm using a container view to hold the table in a section of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are linking with the QuartzCore framework in the target properties page.

On the view controller add:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then you can set the corner radius of the table view's layer like so:

```
_tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
```

Use any value that suits you.

Comment: Very clean and concise, awesome answer!